# Unexpected behaviour with pattern matching on List

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Why the following code print `one` in both cases.

```
 oneOrList(o: Any) = o match  {
  case List => "list"
  case _ => "one"
}

println(oneOrList(1))
println(oneOrList(List(1, 2)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `List` in your `case List =>` is not a type discrimination, it's a test of the target of the match (technically called the *scrutinee*) against the singleton `List` object used mainly to provide the `List(v1, v2, v3, ...)` factory via its `apply` method.

Answer (score 3):

`case List => "list"` would match only against List singleton object. So it would match only `oneOrList(List)`
To match against lists use this:

```
oneOrList(o: Any) = o match  {
  case x: List[_] => "list"
  case _ => "one"
}

println(oneOrList(1))
println(oneOrList(List(1, 2)))
```

Comment: The suggested code is correct but the explanation most certainly is not!